# Guzzle ClientException - Invalid XML data

Tags: php, xml, http, post, guzzle

I need to send a post request with Guzzle for a project I am working on and keep getting a 400 Bad request error with the message 'Invalid XML Data'. I tried lots of different combinations as far as the settings go and am getting the same error message in all cases.

Did anyone else run into this issue? Any ideas why this is? I appreciate any help in advance.

```
$xml = $this->getXml();
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

try {
   $credentials = base64_encode('username:pass');
   $res = $client->post('https://www.example.com',['headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=UTF8', 'Authorization' => 'Basic '.$credentials], 'body' => $xml]);

} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
   dd($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
}
```

For the $xml value, I tried the following:

```
 $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
   <GetCustomerInfo xmlns="http://tempUri.org/">
<CustomerID>1</CustomerID> 
<OutputParam /> 
  </GetCustomerInfo>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';
```

My main objective for the time being is to simply resolve this specific client error for invalid XML and reach the server.

Comment: None of those are valid xml strings.

Comment: Then the validator is wrong or you left something out. This was just referring to the document that just contained `<note>` not your current edit.

Comment: @Event, understood. Thanks for clarifying. Atlhough, even after the edit, with the current XML, I am still getting the same exact error. :/

Answer (score 0):

The XML looks good, so the code should work. Do you have more details in the response? Maybe position in the XML or something else.

Just a side note: you can use `auth` option instead of setting `Authentication` header by hands.